# Valgrind error when loading font in SFML project

Tags: c++, valgrind, sfml

This code:

```cpp
// g++ sfml.cpp -o sfml_test -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("font.ttf"))
    {
        std::cout << "ruh oh" << std::endl;
    }

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");

    return 0;
}
```

...causes valgrind to report two identical errors from two contexts:

```
valgrind ./sfml_test
==7557==  Invalid read of size 8
==7557==    at 0x401D734: strncmp (strcmp.S:175)
==7557==    by 0x400604D: is_dst (dl-load.c:209)
==7557==    by 0x4008566: _dl_dst_count (dl-load.c:246)
==7557==    by 0x4008757: expand_dynamic_string_token (dl-load.c:388)
==7557==    by 0x40088D1: fillin_rpath.isra.0 (dl-load.c:460)
==7557==    by 0x4008BE1: decompose_rpath (dl-load.c:631)
==7557==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:673)
==7557==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:654)
==7557==    by 0x4009745: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2074)
==7557==    by 0x400DDC0: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==7557==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==7557==    by 0x400E138: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==7557==    by 0x4013DAA: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==7557==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==7557==  Address 0x5a25719 is 9 bytes inside a block of size 15 alloc'd
==7557==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7557==    by 0x401C29A: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==7557==    by 0x4008B74: decompose_rpath (dl-load.c:606)
==7557==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:673)
==7557==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:654)
==7557==    by 0x4009745: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2074)
==7557==    by 0x400DDC0: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==7557==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==7557==    by 0x400E138: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==7557==    by 0x4013DAA: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==7557==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==7557==    by 0x40138F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==7557==    by 0x545C257: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:66)
==7557==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
```

When the five font loading lines are removed, valgrind reports no errors. The font file sits alongside the executable sfml_test.

The program executes correctly regardless of the errors and the fonts are loaded and usable. Any ideas on how to remove the valgrind errors?

I am on linux and cannot remember how I installed SFML. I may have just run:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

I can't figure out a way to check my SFML version but it will be either 2.5/2.6.

My OS is PureOS version 10 (debian fork), my g++ version is (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110 (if that makes sense), my glibc version is 2.31.

The full valgrind output is:

```
==11908== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11908== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11908== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11908== Command: ./sfml_test
==11908== 
==11908== Invalid read of size 8
==11908==    at 0x401D734: strncmp (strcmp.S:175)
==11908==    by 0x400604D: is_dst (dl-load.c:209)
==11908==    by 0x4008566: _dl_dst_count (dl-load.c:246)
==11908==    by 0x4008757: expand_dynamic_string_token (dl-load.c:388)
==11908==    by 0x40088D1: fillin_rpath.isra.0 (dl-load.c:460)
==11908==    by 0x4008BE1: decompose_rpath (dl-load.c:631)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:673)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:654)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2074)
==11908==    by 0x400DDC0: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==    by 0x400E138: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==11908==    by 0x4013DAA: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==  Address 0x5a25719 is 9 bytes inside a block of size 15 alloc'd
==11908==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==11908==    by 0x401C29A: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==11908==    by 0x4008B74: decompose_rpath (dl-load.c:606)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:673)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:654)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2074)
==11908==    by 0x400DDC0: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==    by 0x400E138: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==11908==    by 0x4013DAA: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==    by 0x40138F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==11908==    by 0x545C257: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:66)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908== 
==11908== Invalid read of size 8
==11908==    at 0x401D734: strncmp (strcmp.S:175)
==11908==    by 0x400604D: is_dst (dl-load.c:209)
==11908==    by 0x400861E: _dl_dst_substitute (dl-load.c:288)
==11908==    by 0x40088D1: fillin_rpath.isra.0 (dl-load.c:460)
==11908==    by 0x4008BE1: decompose_rpath (dl-load.c:631)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:673)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:654)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2074)
==11908==    by 0x400DDC0: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==    by 0x400E138: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==11908==    by 0x4013DAA: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==    by 0x40138F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==11908==  Address 0x5a25719 is 9 bytes inside a block of size 15 alloc'd
==11908==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==11908==    by 0x401C29A: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==11908==    by 0x4008B74: decompose_rpath (dl-load.c:606)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:673)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: cache_rpath (dl-load.c:654)
==11908==    by 0x4009745: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2074)
==11908==    by 0x400DDC0: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==    by 0x400E138: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==11908==    by 0x4013DAA: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908==    by 0x40138F9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==11908==    by 0x545C257: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:66)
==11908==    by 0x4C0CACF: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==11908== 
==11908== 
==11908== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11908==     in use at exit: 199,041 bytes in 2,589 blocks
==11908==   total heap usage: 28,778 allocs, 26,189 frees, 8,662,565 bytes allocated
==11908== 
==11908== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11908==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11908==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11908==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11908==    still reachable: 199,041 bytes in 2,589 blocks
==11908==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11908== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11908== 
==11908== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==11908== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: What if you completely remove all the lines _except_ loading the font? What if you remove just the inner `while`? What if you don't draw any shapes? Can the example be minified even more somehow?

Comment: Does ASAN agree with valgrind?

Comment: Valgrind allows you to define suppressions for errors beyond your control. See [the documentation](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) especially the `--gen-suppressions=yes` argument.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

@yeputons Remove all lines bar font = no error. Remove all lines bar RenderWindow setup = no error. Remove all lines bar font and RenderWindow setup = error. Hope that helps. Should I edit the question code?

Comment: @bitmask I have never used that, I can look into it.

Comment: @Botje With the valgrind error here, am I right thinking it is saying a malformed call to strncmp is responsible?

Comment: @Momus You can just add `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to the compiler flags and you get asan and ubsan built into the binary. It catches a lot.

Comment: @Momus Hard to say without exact version numbers, but it looks like your version of `strncmp` consumes the input strings 8 bytes at a time for speed. (based on the passed `n` parameter) if the input string only has 15 bytes, then a read of 8 bytes starting from position 9 will read just past the end. This is harmless. Usually :)

Comment: Could you post the full valgrind output? Is `dl_open` missing in valgrind output? What is your environment? What operating system and version? What is your glibc or musl or other C standard library version? What compiler version are you using?

Comment: @bitmask I added `-fsanitize=address` to the compiler command, compiled and then did `./sfml_test`. The code executed but nothing asan specific was printed to the console. The code, when compiled and run with valgrind, produces the error.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have added info to the question which hopefully answer your questions.

Comment: @Momus That *could* mean that it is a false positive, but valgrind does find strictly more than asan, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
==7557==    at 0x401D734: strncmp (strcmp.S:175)
```

Memcheck should be redirecting strncmp. If it isn't then either you are using an old version of Valgrind (most likely) or you are using a libc that has a `strncmp` that Valgrind does not detect (less likely).

Edit:
OP added more details, using Valgrind 3.16.1 from about 7 years ago.

Looks like this was fixed in 2019:

```
Author: Mike Crowe <mac@mcrowe.com>  2019-09-09 15:16:16
Committer: Mark Wielaard <mark@klomp.org>  2022-05-14 00:41:18
Parent: 53dd9bd255d7add6f5a502ec9cd4895d3ed21452 (FreeBSD support, patch 9)
Child:  4fb52a67b5650ecc3c7d90d39ab2dc67b4476505 (Cleanup of str* and mem* functions)
Branches: master, remotes/origin/master and many more (23)
Follows: VALGRIND_3_19_0
Precedes: VALGRIND_3_20_0

    Intercept strncmp for glibc ld.so v2.28+
    
    In glibc 5aad5f617892e75d91d4c8fb7594ff35b610c042 (first released in
    v2.28) a call to strncmp was added to dl-load.c:is_dst. This causes
    valgrind to complain about glibc's highly-optimised strncmp performing
    sixteen-byte reads on short strings in ld.so. Let's intercept strncmp in
    ld.so too so we use valgrind's simple version to avoid this problem.
```

Comment: Yep, my linux distro uses valgrind 3.16.1 and valgrind current release is 3.22. This could be it.

Comment: note to self - when asking question about valgrind, always include valgrind version (smh)

Comment: Been unable to install a more recent valgrind but am marking as accepted as almost sure this is the reason

Comment: Valgrind isn't difficult to build from source (though admittedly I done it countless times), See https://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html.

Comment: I followed your link and installed valgrind version 3.23.0.GIT. This all worked and yes, the errors disappeared! When trying to install a new valgrind yesterday, I went to https://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html, downloaded the tar and performed the same steps yet for some reason it didn't work. Your method was easy and good!